# show alert in the actual viewing view controller

Tags: ios, swift, alert

in my swift 2 app i set this simple code in my app delegate:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
  print("HERE I AM")
}
```

this works fine. if i start my app from background to foreground (become active) the print line will be shown.

but now i would like to realize to show an alert message in the actual viewing view controller.

i know that i setup an alert controller like this:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "MY TITLE", message: "MY TEXT", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in}
alertController.addAction(action)
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

but how can i show the alert controller out of the app delegate in the actual view controller?

Answer (score 0):

okay, i was to fast with my question.
i tried and found my solution:

```
var topViewController = self.window?.rootViewController
while topViewController?.presentedViewController != nil
  {
    topViewController = topViewController?.presentedViewController
  }

let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "TITLE", message: "TEXT", preferredStyle: .Alert)
let action= UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) in}
alertController.addAction(action)

topViewController!.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guess what you are looking for is to receive some info in your ViewController if the Application becomes active. You can achieve this by observing the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` on your ViewController.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(showAlert), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
}

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func showAlert() {
        print("Show Alert")
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.